# How to check Pin Points and merge text - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Pin Points: When a case is cited multiple times with different pin points, all the entries should be considered as one entry in table. In the example, first entry (932, 942) and the second entry (932, 945) are the pin point values. And the final output should be a single entry with any common pin points, 932 in this case
**Input XML**

```
<root>
<p><styled-content><italic>Agarwal v Johnson </italic>(1979) 25 C3d 932, 942, overruled on other grounds in <italic>White v Ultramar, Inc.</italic> (1999) 21 C4th 563</styled-content></p>
<p><styled-content><italic>Agarwal v Johnson </italic>(1979) 25 C3d 932, 942, overruled on other grounds in <italic>White v Ultramar, Inc.</italic> (1999) 21 C4th 563</styled-content></p>
<p><styled-content><italic>Agarwal v Johnson </italic>(1979) 25 C3d 932, 945, overruled on other grounds in <italic>White v Ultramar, Inc.</italic> (1999) 21 C4th 563</styled-content></p>
<p><styled-content><italic>Advantacare Health Partners </italic>(1994) US Dist Lexis</styled-content></p>
<p><styled-content><italic>Advantacare Health Partners </italic>(1994) US Dist Lexis</styled-content></p>
<p><styled-content><italic>Alexander v Gardner-Denver Co.</italic> (1974) 415 US 36, 52 n15, 94 S Ct 1011</styled-content></p>
<p><styled-content><italic>Alexander v Gardner-Denver Co.</italic> (1974) 415 US 36, 94 S Ct 1011</styled-content></p>
</root>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
    <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-by="styled-content">
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        <p>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<root>
<p>Agarwal v Johnson (1979) 25 C3d 932, overruled on other grounds in White v Ultramar, Inc. (1999) 21 C4th 563</p>
<p>Advantacare Health Partners (1994) US Dist Lexis</p>
<p>Alexander v Gardner-Denver Co. (1974) 415 US 36, 94 S Ct 1011</p>
</root>
```

Comment: So what is the data to group by, the case name inside the first `italic` child element, e.g. `Agarwal v Johnson ` or `Advantacare Health Partners `? It should be easy to use `xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-by="styled-content/italic[1]"`. Then don't use `copy-of` inside but push the contents through some template that strips the textual data you want to eliminate, either using replace or analyze-string. If you want to group on part of the text nodes like only those numbers then write a function extracting them and call it in `group-by`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have used group by, because same text multiples entry so I have fetch only single entry. If some entry come Pin pints then how to replace first cite?

Comment: You fail to clearly comunicate the criteria you want to group by and my comment is an attempt to ask you to describe them clearly. For instance, for the first three `p` elements, it seems that `substring-before(., ',')` could be used to identify a common grouping key. But your other two `p` elements do not seem to have any comma nor any number like 932, so it is not clear which data you want to group by.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Can you help me? My regex not properly working when come numbers inside parentheses I want find only number sequence more then two and return only 1st value. (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/17) See example last line is coming wrong.

Comment: It is hard to tell whether a regular expression suffices and how to define it exactly as you don't explain the rules, it seems `<styled-content><italic>Advantacare Health Partners </italic>(1994) US Dist Lexis</styled-content>` doesn't have any number sequence but from a superficial view of the first sample I would `<styled-content><italic>Alexander v Gardner-Denver Co.</italic> (1974) 415 US 36, 52 n15, 94 S Ct 1011</styled-content>` to have one with `36, 52` and expect the `52` to be eliminated. Yet your sample output contains a sequence for the last group.

Comment: So I am afraid I continue to struggle the exact criteria for your latest grouping/transformation questions and that way it is not really possible to suggest code.

Answer (score 1):

**I have Done**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="p/styled-content" group-by="normalize-space(italic[1])">
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <p>
                <xsl:copy-of select="replace(current-group()[last()], '([0-9]+?, )([0-9]+?, )', '$1')"/>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```